# How replace specific strings on conditions in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, bioinformatics

I have data where I have compressed duplicate gene results to each be in 1 row. This has made some rows filled with commas, I am trying to replace rows which only contain commas with NA. However, I also have rows with commas and qualitative data I am trying to keep. For example:

```
Gene     Condition
Gene1    Name=Asymmetrical dimethylarginine level, Name=Bipolar disorder and schizophrenia, Name=3-hydroxypropylmercapturic acid levels in smoker
Gene2    Name=blood pressure, Name=diabetes
Gene3    Name=heart disease, , , , , 
Gene4    , , , , , , , , ,
Gene5    NA
Gene6    , , ,
```

Expected output:

```
Gene     Condition
Gene1    Name=Asymmetrical dimethylarginine level, Name=Bipolar disorder and schizophrenia, Name=3-hydroxypropylmercapturic acid levels in smoker
Gene2    Name=blood pressure, Name=diabetes
Gene3    Name=heart disease, , , , , 
Gene4    NA
Gene5    NA
Gene6    NA
#ideally I would get rid of Gene3's extra commas but this is not necessary
```

I am trying to code for a statement like "if the row has only commas in the condition column replace to NA", and trying to do it with a statement like `data$Condition[ if("," & ![A-Z]|[a-z]|[=]) ] <- "NA"` but I'm not sure how to get the syntax right or if this will work for all rows with only commas but the number of commas varies - I am new to R so any guidance would be appreciated.

Example data:

```
DF <-
structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", 
"Gene6"), Condition = c("Name=Asymmetrical dimethylarginine leve,l Name=Bipolar disorder and schizophrenia, Name=3-hydroxypropylmercapturic acid levels in smoker", 
"Name=blood pressure, Name=diabetes", "Name=heart disease, , , , ,", 
", , , , , , , , ,", NA, "Name=kidney disease, , ,")), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option

`grepl(pattern= "^[ ,]+$")`
When the row which only contains blanck space and comma , this function will return TRUE.

```
DF <-
structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", 
"Gene6"), Condition= c("Name=Asymmetrical dimethylarginine leve,l Name=Bipolar disorder and schizophrenia, Name=3-hydroxypropylmercapturic acid levels in smoker", 
"Name=blood pressure, Name=diabetes", "Name=heart disease, , , , ,", 
", , , , , , , , ,", NA, "Name=kidney disease, , ,")), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

DF[which(grepl("^[ ,]+$",DF$Condition)==T),2]<-NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, You can try this for removing commas if a cell contains only commas

```
DF$condition <- gsub('^(,\\s*)+$',NA, DF$Condition)
```

However, if you want to remove trailing commas only and replacing all commas cell with NA then you can try:

```
DF$condition <- gsub('^$', NA, gsub('(,\\s*)+$','', DF$Condition))
```

**1st Output:**

```
> gsub('^(,\\s*)+$',NA, DF$Condition)
[1] "Name=Asymmetrical dimethylarginine leve,l Name=Bipolar disorder and schizophrenia, Name=3-hydroxypropylmercapturic acid levels in smoker"
[2] "Name=blood pressure, Name=diabetes"                                                                                                      
[3] "Name=heart disease, , , , ,"                                                                                                             
[4] NA                                                                                                                                        
[5] NA                                                                                                                                        
[6] "Name=kidney disease, , ,"
```

**2nd Output**:

```
> gsub('^$', NA, gsub('(,\\s*)+$','', DF$Condition))
[1] "Name=Asymmetrical dimethylarginine leve,l Name=Bipolar disorder and schizophrenia, Name=3-hydroxypropylmercapturic acid levels in smoker"
[2] "Name=blood pressure, Name=diabetes"                                                                                                      
[3] "Name=heart disease"                                                                                                                      
[4] NA                                                                                                                                        
[5] NA                                                                                                                                        
[6] "Name=kidney disease"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `grepl` like below, where the lines with `,` only will be set to `NA`

```
DF <- within(DF,Condition <-replace(Condition,!grepl("[[:alnum:]]",Condition),NA))
```